# Scrapy - Running Multiple Spiders at Once - CrawlerProcess - File Structure

Tags: python, scrapy, file-structure

I'm trying to use CrawlerProcess to run multiple Scrapy Spiders at once, but am unsure of the file structure.  Both Spiders work correctly when run individually via `scrapy crawl indeed` and `scrapy crawl monster` (designated names of my spider classes).

My current file structure is as follows:

```
- scrapy
  - tutorial
    - spiders
      - __init__.py
      - indeed_spider.py
      - monster_spider.py
    - __init__.py
    - crawler.py
    - functions.py
    - items.py
    - middlewares.py
    - pipelines.py
    - settings.py
  - scrapy.cfg
```

As you can see, I have my **crawler.py** setup within the main **tutorial** directory.

The code for **crawler.py** is as follows:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from tutorial.spiders.indeed_spider import IndeedSpider
from tutorial.spiders.monster_spider import MonsterSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(IndeedSpider)
process.crawl(MonsterSpider)
process.start()
```

When I enter the **tutorial** directory and run `python crawler.py`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tutorial.spiders.indeed_spider import IndeedSpider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tutorial'
```

This is strange, because there clearly is a `tutorial` module.  There is nothing in the Scrapy documentation about file structure and running multiple spiders at once; it gives a basic example that is little help ([crawler doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process)).

My questions are:

- How does one run multiple spiders via `CrawlerProcess` on the command line?  It is not `scrapy crawl {spider_name}`.  I assume it is `python crawler.py`, but that didn't work given my current structure.
- Where should `crawler.py` be stored in the project directory?
- Is further manipulation of `pipelines.py` or `settings.py` required to initiate `CrawlerProcess`?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Don’t enter the `tutorial` directory, or you are removing `tutorial` from the Python import paths. Run `python tutorial/crawler.py`, or add the path containing the `tutorial` folder to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You made it all correctly, the error is about python's importing execution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tutorial.spiders.indeed_spider import IndeedSpider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tutorial'
```

that's a well known obstacle in python. I suggest to you create a setup.py in scrapy's directory with the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='nameofproject', version='version', packages=find_packages())
```

so your structure should be:

```
> - scrapy
>   - setup.py
>   - tutorial
>     - spiders
>       - __init__.py
>       - indeed_spider.py
>       - monster_spider.py
>     - __init__.py
>     - crawler.py
>     - functions.py
>     - items.py
>     - middlewares.py
>     - pipelines.py
>     - settings.py
>   - scrapy.cfg
```

Then, you must execute inside scrapy's directory the following command in your shell:

```
pip install -e .
```

Now python's interpreter should be able to identify `tutorial` as a module.